# Find GRASS GIS path on Ubuntu

Tags: r, grass-gis, python-3, rgrass7

I want to use algorithms from GRASS GIS in R. One essential step is already providing some serious problems. I managed in some way to install GRASS on Ubuntu 18.04, but now I need to provide the path to the `initGrass()`-function from rgrass7. I tried using the `find2GI`-package to find my GRASS GIS installation but it gives me this error:

```
> link2GI::findGRASS()
Error in gregexpr(pattern = "\"", root_dir)[[1]] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Is there any easy way to just find the path to the binaries of grass. I tried `which grass` aswell but it gives me:
`/usr/bin/grass`, what also doesn't seem to work with `initGrass`

Comment: /usr/bin/grass76 works (check your version)?

Comment: That looks like a bug in `link2GI::findGRASS`, but might be triggered by something unusual in your file arrangement. What does `system2("find", "/usr ! -readable -prune -o -type f -executable -iname 'grass??' -print")` say? This is the Unix command that function uses to try and find grass installations.

Comment: thanks for the answers! The output of that command is `/usr/bin/grass78`. I guess it might be a problem in my file arrangement as it's quite bad...